# Why am I getting duplicate exception entries using ELMAH in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, elmah

I'm brand new to ELMAH but I've been working with MVC for a little while now.  After reading several blogs on the subject I'm pursuing the road of having an `ErrorController` that handles 404 and unknown-error pages, and making a default route that forwards all unknown paths to the 404 action on that controller.

The problem is that **ELMAH logs every error twice**; the detail logs are completely identical except for their identification number specified in brackets in the title.

Has anyone else run into this?  The routing seems to work great apart from having to ditch default `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route.

Here's my configuration:

```
    <configSections>
      ...
            <sectionGroup name="elmah">
                <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
                <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
                <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
                <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
            </sectionGroup>
            ...
   </configSections>
   <system.web>
        ...
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error/unknown/">
                <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/notfound/"/>
        </customErrors>
        ...
        <httpHandlers>
        ...
             <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
        ...
 </httpHandlers>
        ...
        <httpModules>
     ...
            <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
        </httpModules>
     </system.web>
     <system.webserver>
          <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
               ...
               <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
          </modules>
          <handlers>
               ...
               <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
          </handlers>
     </system.webserver>
     <elmah>
         <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/errorlogpath" />
     </elmah>
```

And routing code:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "ErrorDefault",
        "error/{action}",
        new { controller = "error", action = "unknown", id = "" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{*url}",
        new { controller = "error", action = "notfound", id = "" }
        );
```

**EDIT:**  Here's the ErrorController as well, just for my testing purposes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles error page routing
/// </summary>
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Action for unknown errors
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ViewResult Unknown()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return View();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Action for 404s
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ViewResult NotFound(string path)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually log the errors?

Comment: I'm using the error logging method that stores the errors locally in XML files.

Comment: What I meant was if it's the ErrorController that signals the errors to Elmah, or if the ErrorController just shows a generic error page and you do the signalling somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; the ErrorController doesn't signal any errors and I'm not using any derivation of the `HandleError` attribute.  The controller just shows two basic views, and sets the outgoing error code appropriately.

Comment: Did u find a solution for this? I have the same issue and my gut feeling is that there is a duplicate logging entry from web.config

Comment: I had the same thought but I couldn't hunt it down.  We ended up going with a different logging solution, but I've left this up since I'd still like to know what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to ditch the default route?
I see that you're defining an `ErrorDefault` route and a catchAll route, which seems redundant to me. You'd want the catchAll route to handle any unknown route so you'd want to define the error in there.

You could try something like:

```
// All other pages use the default route.
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Applications", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

// Show a 404 error page for anything else.
routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "notfound" }
);
```

Could the redundant route be the cause of the double entries in the error log?